# Upgrading to Laravel 5.2 invalidates all sessions

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-routing, laravel-5

Upgrading from Laravel 5.1.17 to 5.2. My `config/auth.php` originally contained:

```php
'driver' => 'eloquent',
'model'  => 'Project\User',
'table'  => 'users',
```

New file is the same as the default, except with the updated namespace.

```php
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => Project\User::class,
    ],
],
```

My env `SESSION_DRIVER` is `redis`. I did not clear anything from Redis. (Note, this also happened in my other projects where driver was `file`, but I didn't care about it as much for them.)

I have two branches, L5.2 and master (which is on 5.1.17). After switching branches, I simply run `composer install`

> If I **login** on **master**, then switch to **L5.2**, I am logged out
>   If I switch back to **master**, I am logged back in
>   If I **login** on **L5.2**, then switch to **master**, I stay logged in
>   If I switch back to **L5.2**, I stay logged in

I'm hesitant to upgrade if it's going to invalidate all of my users' sessions and force them to login again. Is there a way to avoid this?

The only other files that were modified were `composer.json`, `composer.lock`, `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`, and `config/app.php`; nothing that touched Auth.

Comment: Has nobody else experienced this? This has happened to me on 6 different projects on 2 different servers. I can't be the only one

Comment: I don't understand one thing - you tell that only the only changed files are `composer.json`, `composer.lock` etc (total 4 files) between 5.1.17 and 5.2 but in fact you also changed other files (for example `app/Http/routes.php` to include `web` middleware. Have you changed other files when switching between branches? I mean `Kernel.php` etc?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I only changed routes to test your answer. I reverted it back afterwards. It is just those 4 files

Comment: If you look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0 you will see that you should make much more changes to upgrade to version 5.2 (one of first mentioned is `config/auth.php` so If I were you I would first make sure I have valid `app` structure - the best way would be probably cloning `https://github.com/laravel/laravel` and comparing this with your `app` folder to see all differences and then merge all necessary changes with your code.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I did update `config/auth.php`, that's the main part of the question. Good idea to compare though, I'll try it

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I guess I meant just those **5** files not 4. config/auth.php is part of the question + the 4 mentioned at the end. Everything else in the upgrade guide doesn't apply to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what is causing the session to be invalidated. The problem is the session guard's `getName()` method.

In 5.1.17:

```php
return 'login_'.md5(get_class($this));
```

In 5.2 (`$this->name` would be `web` by default):

```php
return 'login_'.$this->name.'_'.sha1(get_class($this));
```

Also, the class name itself changes from `Guard` to `SessionGuard`

If I replace this method with:

```php
return 'login_'.md5('Illuminate\Auth\Guard');
```

That keeps my sessions logged in.

This is progress but not a complete solution yet. The real solution is to update all of your existing sessions with the new name. I'll work on a script to complete this and then update my answer.

Comment: Good to know. I also thought that something internally could have changed with session names but didn't have time to verify this but this is quite strange so serious change has been made and I haven't seen any info about it in Upgrade guide

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek it would have been hard for you to verify without old session data to compare. That's the only way I figured it out

Comment: Now in upgrade guide to laravel 5.2 there is: `Because of changes to the authentication system, any existing sessions will be invalidated when you upgrade to Laravel 5.2.`

Answer (score 1):

That you should do is open `app/Http/routes.php`

and wrap all your existing routes with:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // here your previous routes
});
```

**EDIT**

After testing I can confirm this behaviour.

In those cases:

- 5.1.17 -> 5.2
- 5.1.23 -> 5.2
- 5.1.28 -> 5.2.*

after upgrade to 5.2 User seems not be logged anymore. When going in versions in 5.1 branch user stays logged. When going back from 5.2 to 5.1 user is logged again.

At the moment you should probably create issue here https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues and wait for response

**EDIT2**

It seems it's official and expected behaviour because to upgrade guide  has been added:

> Because of changes to the authentication system, any existing sessions will be invalidated when you upgrade to Laravel 5.2.

Comment: Did not work. Reflection exception class "web" does not exist. I also tried `auth:web` which did not throw an exception, but it still logs me out

Comment: @andrewtweber Does your Handler look like this: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php ? Have you removed cached files?

Comment: No, it did not have the `$middlewareGroups`. When I add the groups, I can use `middleware => web` as you said in your answer, but it still logs me out of my account. Clearing cache did nothing

Comment: Sorry but I think this is only if you update your `Http/Kernel.php` file with the new middleware groups. If you leave it as is, then all of the old middleware (`EncryptCookies`, `StartSession`, etc.) are inside of the `$middleware` array and are applied to every route by default

Comment: So in other words you can either upgrade both Kernel and routes, or neither

Comment: And it is working for you then? I've updated both and it seemed not to work

Comment: No, if I leave both files without touching them or update both files, either way it doesn't work

Comment: So you should probably put issue on github and wait for answer. At the moment I don't have idea why this happens